# How to retrieve the number from the field in UFT?

Tags: hp-uft

Can you please provide a script where I can get the value "3" and store in a field? Validating number of sales, this number changes every time.

Here is the Obj Rep

```
"Class Name:=WebElement",
"abs_x:=24",
"abs_y:=177",
"acc_name:=",
"class:=indicator",
"height:=67",
"html id:=",
"html tag:=DIV",
"innerhtml:=3",
"innertext:=3",
"outerhtml:=<div class=""indicator"" _ngcontent-c7="""">3</div>",
"outertext:=3",
"role:=",
"title:=",
"type:=",
"visible:=True",
"width:=54",
"x:=24",
"xpath:=//DIV\[@id=""number of sales""\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[1\]",
"y:=177"
```

Comment: In general, readers do not write scripts on request here, so I would suggest you change your question. They will help you modify a script you have written though, providing you understand that you'll be doing the work. Are you able to provide what you have written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to remove the innertext and innerhtml form the OR object properties. Then use `GetROProperty` to retrieve the value from the application.

```
Browser().Page().WebElement().GetROProperty("innertext")
```

Btw if you are mentioning all the properties that mentioned in the question as part OR Object Identification strategy, you have to seriously consider updating it. I think you can remove everything except the `class` or `xpath`, that will identify the element uniquely.

And if you don't remove the innertext and innerhtml from the OR Object identification properties then your test will fail if the number `3` changes in future. If you still want to maintain all the properties then you just have to check the `.exists` on the element to validate the text `=3` as the webelement itself have `innertext:3`

Comment: One last help..Can we directly use xpath properties in UFT??. The below one is not working.."xpath:=//DIV\[@id=""inSales""\]/DIV\[1\]/Sale-ENTRY\[3\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[1\]/DIV\[3\]/DIV\[2\]/DIV\[2\]/DIV\[1\]",

Comment: I would suggest create another post and also provide either the html or the screenshot of the html for the element from "inSales" tag. The xpath you mentioned above is not correct. The general notation for xpath is `//tag[@property='property_value']"`.